# PHP/AJAX importing XML data into MySQL db not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, xml

I am trying to use `PHP`/`Ajax` to upload an `XML` file and import the data into my database. It all seems to be running smoothly, I have the button working and a function to notify me whether the file has been uploaded or not, however when I go to look in my database, the information isn't there.

(I was following a tutorial, trying to adapt it to my own needs/XML file structure).

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) &&  $_FILES['file']['name'] != '')
{
    $valid_extension = array('xml');
    $file_data = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $file_extension = end($file_data);
    if(in_array($file_extension, $valid_extension))
    {
        $data = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hpr_db','root','root');
        $query = "
        INSERT INTO data(userid, firstname, lastname, objectid, productkey, logvolume, loglength)
        VALUES(:userid, :firstname, :lastname, :objectid, :productkey, :logvolume, :loglength);";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)

        $statement->execute(
            array(
            ':userid'       =>  $data->Machine->MachineUserID,
            ':firstname'    =>  $data->Machine->OperatorDefinition->ContactInformation[$i]->FirstName,
            ':lastname'     =>  $data->Machine->OperatorDefinition->ContactInformation[$i]->LastName,
            ':objectid'     =>  $data->Machine->ObjectDefinition[$i]->ObjectUserID,
            ':productkey'   =>  $data->Machine->SingleTreeProcessedStem->Log[$i]>ProductKey,
            ':logvolume'    =>  $data->Machine->SingleTreeProcessedStem->Log[$i]->LogVolume,
            ':loglength'    =>  $data->Machine->SingleTreeProcessedStem->Log->LogMeasurement[$i]->LogLength,
            )
        );
    }

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    if(isset($result))
    {
        $output = '<div class="alert alert-success">Import Data Done</div>';
    }
}
else
{
    $output = '<div class="alert alert-warning">Invalid File</div>';
}
```

I am very new to this so please be kind.

What does the [$i] mean after the node in the array? I have a feeling the complexity of my XML file is making it confusing, am I putting it the wrong position? The tutorial XML file only has 2 nodes so it is structured as such;

```
':name'     =>  $data->employee[$i]->name,
':position'     =>  $data->employee[$i]->position,
```

For more complex `XML` files, what would be the structure? Or am I completely missing the point.

Answer (score 0):

I had same need and finally used [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel):

First you need to use from [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). After that read your xls file and insert data to your database.

Read and convert your xls file to to PHP array with following structure:

```
function fileInitializer($file, $needCells){
 $array_data = array();
 require_once 'libraries/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
 $target_dir = "FILEPATH/".$file;
 $objReader= new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
 $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
 $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load( $target_dir);
 $rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();
 $rowIndex = 0;
 foreach($rowIterator as $row){
     $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
     $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); 
     if(1 == $row->getRowIndex ()) continue;

    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        foreach($needCells as $needCell){
            if($needCell['cell_name'] == $cell->getColumn()){
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$needCell['array_name']] = fai_convert_string_to_persian($cell->getCalculatedValue());
            } 
        }
    }
    $rowIndex++;
}
return $array_data;
}
$file = 'FILENAME';
$needCells = array(
     array('cell_name'=>'A', 'array_name'=>'id')
    , array('cell_name'=>'B', 'array_name'=>'full_name')
);
$array_data = fileInitializer($file, $needCells);
```

and after above process have a while in $array_data and add data to your database